# How to change separator in openCSV?

Tags: java, spring, csv, opencsv

I have the following code that works perfectly except for the thing that separator is still a coma:

```
CsvToBeanBuilder<CsvProductDto>(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content)))
            .withSeparator('|')
            .withType(CsvProductDto.class)
            .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
            .build()
            .parse()
```

How to change the separator?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've figured this out. You need to build your own parser and builder, so  it looks like this in Kotlin:

```
val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(content))
val icsvParser = CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator('|').build()
val readerRfc = CSVReaderBuilder(reader).withCSVParser(icsvParser).build()

list = CsvToBeanBuilder<CsvProductDto>(readerRfc)
            .withType(CsvProductDto::class.java)
            .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
            .build()
            .parse()
```